# How to force MatrixPlot to differentiate distinct expr?

Tags: plotting, matrix

I thought `MatrixPlot` can differentiate different expressions in color until I found this:

```
SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {E^-I, E^I, E^I, E^-I, E^-I, E^I}] // MatrixPlot
```

[image: my MatrixPlot]

`MatrixPlot` can't differentiate `E^-I` from `E^I`!!!!

But I use `MatrixPlot` to get a first impression of how many different expressions are there and how they are located in a newly generated matrix?

So here is the question:

> How to force `MatrixPlot` to differentiate every distinct expression?

Comment: `SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {E^-I, E^I, E^I, E^-I, E^-I, E^I}] // 
  Im // MatrixPlot`

Comment: "MatrixPlot can't differentiate E^-I from E^I!!!!". It can, but only if it gets input it can work with, i.e. real numbers.

Comment: @Graumagier well, so what I am asking is to find a way to let `MatrixPlot` differentiate every distinct expr without supplying it with numbers

Comment: @matheorem – eldo's comment should help you with that.

Comment: @eldo This is to specific, what if there are other kind of expr that `MatrixPlot` can't differentiate, we don't know

Comment: Right, so we don't even know if MatrixPlot is the right tool in those cases. Maybe you should be more specific about which cases you want to catch.

Comment: @Graumagier general case, just any possible matrix element expr

Comment: @matheorem – I don't think this will work without at least a basic idea of what output to expect. Maybe just generate two `MatrixPlot`s, one for the real and one for the imaginary part? You could even overlay them like `array = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {E^-I, E^I, E^I, E^-I, E^-I, E^I}];
Overlay[{
  MatrixPlot@Re@array,
  MatrixPlot@Im@array
  },
 BaseStyle -> Opacity[0.5]
 ]`.

Comment: @Graumagier I just got an idea, see my answer :)

Answer (score 7):

got an idea, use `Hash` function. `Hash` function will generate very different hash code for different expr

```
mat=SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {E^-I, E^I, E^I, E^-I, E^-I, E^I}]

MatrixPlot[Map[Hash,Normal@mat,{2}],ColorFunction->Hue]
```

[image]

---

I wrote a function `colormat` to color matrix with any expressions and to make it as colorful as possible

```
    Clear[colormat];
colormat[mat_] := Module[{},
  tmpmat = Map[Hash[#] &, Normal@mat, {2}] /. Hash[0] -> 0;
  tallyelement = Tally@Flatten@tmpmat;
  fcol = Hue;(*ColorData["CMYKColors"]*)
  customhuelist[n_] := 
   fcol[#[[1]], #[[2]], 1] & /@ 
    Transpose@{Subdivide[0, 0.9, n - 1], 
      Take[Flatten@Table[{0.35, 0.55, 1}, 30], n]};
  If[MemberQ[tallyelement, 0, -1], 
   customcolorrule = 
    Thread[Sort@tallyelement[[;; , 1]] -> 
      Prepend[customhuelist[Length[tallyelement] - 1], White]], 
   customcolorrule = 
    Thread[tallyelement[[;; , 1]] -> 
      customhuelist[Length[tallyelement]]]];
  MatrixPlot[#[[1]], ColorRules -> customcolorrule, 
     PlotLabel -> #[[2]]] & /@ {{tmpmat, "mat"}, {Re@mat, 
     "Re@mat"}, {Im@mat, "Im@mat"}}]
```

Now for matrix like following

```
colormat[{{a, b, d}, {e, f, g}, {h, i, j}}]
```

will give

[image]

I keep the last two plot as default `MatrixPlot` of Re and Im for possible reference.

If we directly use `Hash` or bill s `ToCharacterCode` will give

[image]

So you can see how colorful `colormat` can give :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to approach this is to turn each item in the list into a string, then transform the string to charactercodes, which are numbers that can be plotted by `MatrixPlot`.

```
mat = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {E^-I, E^I, E^I, E^-I, E^-I, E^I}];
MatrixPlot[Map[Total, ToCharacterCode /@ Map[ToString, Normal[mat], {2}], {2}],
           ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image]

Comment: The interesting thing is why we got the same color?

Comment: I think it's coincidence because the numbers in the matrices are very different.

Comment: Modified to match purpose of question...`Im` seems the most natural choice

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
mat = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {E^-I, E^I, E^I, E^-I, E^-I, E^I}];
```

*Auxiliary.* Nonzero values:

```
nzv[mat_] := Sort@DeleteDuplicates@SparseArray[mat]["NonzeroValues"];
```

*Index function.* Assign a positive integer index to each nonzero expression in the matrix `mat`.

```
Clear[idxFN];
idxFN[mat_] := With[{a = AssociationThread[# -> Range@Length@# &@nzv[mat]]},
   Lookup[a, #, 0] &];

MatrixPlot[Map[idxFN[mat], mat, {2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*A `ColorFunction`* that assigns a different color to each expression in `mat`. Adding the default color function made it look at little complicated, but it's basically the same idea as the indexing function.

```
Clear[colorFN];
colorFN[mat_, 
        cf_:  (* default color function with default rescaling *)
          Composition[
            "DefaultColorFunction" /.
              (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Default", MatrixPlot]), 
            0.5 + 0.5 # &],
        default_: White] :=
  With[{a = AssociationThread[# -> cf /@ (N@Range@Length@#/Length[#]) &@ nzv[mat]],
        d = default /. Automatic -> cf[0]}},
   Lookup[a, #, d] &];
```

The usual use should use `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`:

```
MatrixPlot[mat, ColorFunction -> colorFN[mat], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Other styling options:

```
MatrixPlot[mat,
 ColorFunction -> colorFN[mat, ColorData@"Rainbow", Blue],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MatrixPlot[mat,
 ColorFunction -> colorFN[mat, ColorData@"LakeColors", Automatic],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Upvoted, what I want to do in `colormat` has the same effect as indexing different expr. But I done it stupidly. Very clever method!

Comment: BTW, what does `Composition[
 "DefaultColorFunction" /. (Method /. 
    Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Default", MatrixPlot]), 0.5 + 0.5 # &]` mean? `Charting`ResolvePlotTheme` ?

Comment: @matheorem Thanks.  `ResolvePlotTheme` is a way to look up some default settings for various plotting functions.  Search for it on this site, and you'll find some other uses.  The default behavior of `MatrixPlot` seems to scale the input to the default color function so that the matrix value `0` corresponds to the color function value  `0.5`.  Therefore I composed with `0.5 + 0.5 # &`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply colorize by the complex phase

```
mat = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {E^-I, E^I, E^I, E^-I, E^-I, E^I}];
MatrixPlot[mat, ColorFunction -> (Hue[Arg@#/2/π, Abs@#] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]